# If Excel has an accuracy of 15 significant figures, why are there presets for number styles with > 15 decimal places?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

[image]

And what is the difference if it was 0,############... or #,########...?

Comment: Where do you get the information from that Excel has an accuracy that can be measured in decimal places? It is very likely to be incorrect.

Comment: @DanielB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Number formats with more decimal places are still useful when the first decimal digits are zero.  So 0,000000000000000000000000012345678901234 can be presented completely. Also 0,### will show the first zero, #,### will start with the decimal point (or comma)

Comment: 64-bit memory access has no impact whatsoever on arithmetic precision.

Comment: @LPChip just checked Excel 365 on 64 bit platform - and yes, it's still 15 digits.

Comment: @Paul thanks for checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [difference between](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/84555) *significant figures* and *decimal places*.

Excel calculates to [approximately 15 significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel). Those significant figures can be anywhere in the valid number range, so a display showing 20 decimal places could still have 15 significant figures.